# Execute multiple commands in one line through ssh starting with pkill -f

Tags: pkill

Noticed something strange while working with a raspberry pi.

Using pkill with no options allows me to run other commands afterwards in the same line, but if I use the option -f, then subsequent commands are ignored. Does anyone know why?

```
$ ssh pi@192.168.1.1 "pkill -f blablabla ; echo yeaaaah"
pi@192.168.1.1's password:


$ ssh pi@192.168.1.1 "pkill blablabla ; echo yeaaaah"
pi@192.168.1.1's password:
yeaaaah
```

It makes no difference whether process blablabla exists or not.

Answer (score 4):

Because `-f` allows `pkill` to match anywhere in the command line, it matches `blablabla` in the argument list of the remote shell, and kills that.

You can see what's happening if you run `pgrep -af` instead:

```
$ ssh steeldriver@192.168.1.18 "pgrep -af blablabla ; echo yeaaaah"
steeldriver@192.168.1.18's password:
29223 bash -c pgrep -af blablabla ; echo yeaaaah
yeaaaah
```

Comment: Ooooooohhh, of course! Many thanks!